# AWS Step-Functions SQS CreateQueue Fifo Support

Tags: aws-step-functions, aws-sqs-fifo

I'm designing a state machine in AWS Step Functions. I planned to use SQS in order to give status update to backend API. SQS type should be Fifo since the messages should be delivered in same order that are created. I'm using user id as QueueName and formatting it to make it comply with fifo requirements.

**Pass State** (is combined under *transformInputs* resultpath)

```
  "sqsParameters": {
    "queueName.$": "States.Format('{}.fifo',$.session.sqsQueueName)",
    "messageGroupId.$": "$.session.sqsQueueName"
  }
```

**Amazon SQS CreateQueue State**

```
{
  "QueueName.$": "$.transformInputs.sqsParameters.queueName"
}
```

Actual input that is supplied to `$.session.sqsQueueName` is `test`

In the Pass state this name is converted into `test.fifo`

Above transformation works fine and I get whatever I expect in the input section of CreateQueue State.

**Problem**:

When I execute the state machine it gives the following exception.

```
Error

Sqs.SqsException
Cause

Can only include alphanumeric characters, hyphens, or underscores. 1 to 80 in length (Service: Sqs, Status Code: 400, Request ID: a20c3c98-239b-4686-9030-26704d0f844d, Extended Request ID: null)
```

I can verify what is passed into API from taskscheduled section of logs

```
11  TaskScheduled   CreateQueue - ...
{
  "resourceType": "aws-sdk:sqs",
  "resource": "createQueue",
  "region": "eu-masked-1",
  "parameters": {
    "QueueName": "test.fifo"
  },
  "timeoutInSeconds": null,
  "heartbeatInSeconds": null
}
```

Then I add `FifoQueue` attribute as explained in API documentation https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/APIReference/API_CreateQueue.html
API Parameters section in the design form of WorkFlow Studio

```
{
  "QueueName.$": "$.transformInputs.sqsParameters.queueName",
  "FifoQueue" : true
}
```

This time it gives following exception when I try to save the work flow:

```
There are Amazon States Language errors in your state machine definition. Fix the errors to continue.
The field "FifoQueue" is not supported by Step Functions
For more information, see Amazon States Language
```

**Json Definition which corresponds to SQS Queue Creation State**

```
    "CreateQueue": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Next": "Batch SubmitJob",
      "Parameters": {
        "QueueName.$": "$.transformInputs.sqsParameters.queueName",
        "FifoQueue": true
      },
      "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::aws-sdk:sqs:createQueue",
      "ResultPath": "$.createQueue"
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way of creating FIFO queues from inside step-functions which worked for me. (Amazon SQS: CreateQueue Stage)

```json
{
  "QueueName.$": "States.Format('{}.fifo',$.sqsQueueName)",
  "Attributes": {
    "FifoQueue": "true",
    "ContentBasedDeduplication": "true"
  }
}
```

And here is sample Send message format: (Amazon SQS: SendMessage Stage)

```json
{
  "QueueUrl.$": "$.createQueue.QueueUrl",
  "MessageGroupId.$": "$$.Execution.Name",
  "MessageBody": {
    "message": "Job Succeeded",
    "trace.$": "$"
  }
}
```

**Notes**:

- *MessageGroupId* is important, otherwise it will fail. You can assign anything. In the above example `$$.Execution.Name` is provided as MessageGroupId, which refers to the Context object's Execution Name of the state machine's actively running cycle. Ex: `b3d429a5-d499-5806-095d-524384x937d2`
- If you do not assign *ContentBasedDeduplication* as true then you should provide a *MessageDeduplicationId* field with a unique id on each message which is something hard to achieve in step-functions without the help of lambda.
- Check *Add original input to output using ResultPath* and choose *Combine original input with result* then enter a value such as `$.createQueue` in **Output** tab of the CreateQueue Stage. This provide you with `$.createQueue.QueueUrl` along with other variables coming from previous stages.
- CreateQueue does also work if queue already exists. It provides you the queueUrl in each execution, to be consumed in the next stages. It only fails if you try to change a property on an existing queue.

**State Definition**:

```json
"CreateQueue": {
  "Type": "Task",
  "Next": "Command Selector",
  "Parameters": {
    "QueueName.$": "States.Format('{}.fifo',$.sqsQueueName)",
    "Attributes": {
      "FifoQueue": "true",
      "ContentBasedDeduplication": "true"
    }
  },
  "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::aws-sdk:sqs:createQueue",
  "ResultPath": "$.createQueue"
}
```

Here is the API Reference where you may find other attributes.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/APIReference/API_CreateQueue.html

Answer (score 0):

Replace the parameters block with this:

```
"Parameters": {
    "QueueName.$": "$.transformInputs.sqsParameters.queueName",
    "Attributes": {"FifoQueue": true}
  },
```

(I ran into this today, the docs aren't good...)

Comment: Thanks Andy. Your answer led me into the solution. I would like to make a small correction though. true should be double quoted such as "true" otherwise it gives string expected kind of exception.